# count by column name

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, netezza

```
Trans|Store|Date
1    | 10  |9/01/13
2    | 10  |9/01/13
3    | 20  |9/01/13
4    | 10  |9/02/13
```

What I am trying to query is

(For Date = 9/01/13)

```
Store|#Trans|Date
10   | 2    |9/01/13
20   | 1    |9/01/13
```

How do I achieve this any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:-

```
select store, count(*) as Transt from table
where Date = '9/01/13' 
group by store
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me number of Trans, how do I query Store number associated with it.

Comment: @user2816977:- Updated my answer. Hope that works!!!

Comment: @user2816977:- Does that work for you??

Comment: Also how can I add a third column of Date in this query which in this case would just show '9/01/13' for all the rows.

Comment: select store, count(*), Date as Transt from table...the rest of the answer.

Comment: @NathanTempelman does not work. select StoreNum, count (*) as TransNum, TransDate from Table where TransDate = '9/01/13' Group by StoreNum

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't do it, this might.

```
Select
         count(Store) as #Trans,
         Store
    from
         tablename
    where
         Date = '9/01/13'
    group by
         Store
```

This smells like homework something fierce though.

Comment: I dont think OP is looking for this!!! :)

Comment: Seems like he's trying to get all the rows with a particular date, no? Pretty much the most basic SQL you could think up

Comment: Unless he's trying to get them ordered in a certain way? And only one per store per day? OP, what say you?

Comment: Yes I agree that it is quite basic but you didnt read the whole question. OP wants the count for store

Comment: Oh, I see now. Your updated way seems like it'd do the trick. I'll give it an upvote if you like, OP doesn't seem able to.

Comment: Yes I am trying to see store 10 had how many transactions on 9/1. store 20 had how many, so forth for all the way for all the 100+ stores. So I am trying to see the store # as column 1 & # of trans in column 2.

Comment: I would suggest you to delete your answer as it is not what OP is looking for OR you may edit and improve it else you may end up getting some downvotes for a very basic question :)

Comment: I thought I'd improve it on the off chance your way didn't work for OP for some reason. But it seems it worked for him, so upvotes for you

Comment: Also how can I add a third column of Date in this query which in this case would just show '9/01/13' for all the returned rows.